# Writing out a callout from a database using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I have a problem that I just cannot figure out on my own. This is the issue.

I'm making a website that is using javascript to make the website write out things as you type on your keyboard using JS. As you're 'writing' this text I would like your location to be shown, making the illusion that you're the actual person writing. I solved this problem by calling the IP adress and translating it to a city and country using google maps or something like that. The issue now is to get this to 'write it out' as actual text. Take a look at this fiddle -

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RagdVB

`Hello, I am viewing this page from <span id="usergeoip">unknown location</span>.`

In this example you can see how its supposed to be, but the problem is that I cannot use `<span id>` inside the text because it inflicts with the other js making the code be 'typed out'. Is there a solution for calling out this location without using `<span>` or `<p>` or such, or is that impossible?

Comment: Why don't you put the typeout in a different span from the one that displays the location?

Comment: Can you provide the code that does your typing out? you probably are just selecting all `span` tags in the type out code